# C#: Net Core 3.1 Contains Linq causes Client Side Exception Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

The following is throwing a Client Side Exception error in Net Core 3.1

Not sure why, PropertyIdentifier is in Property Entity Data table and class.

Does anyone know how to fix?

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<PropertyDto>> GetByPropertyIdentifier(List<string> identifiers)
    {
        var properties = await _dataContext.Property
            .Where(x => identifiers.Contains(x.PropertyIdentifier))
            .ToListAsync();

        return properties.Select(_mapper.Map);
    }
```

> Error: error: "Invalid request: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => __identifiers_0.Contains(p.PropertyIdentifier))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Resource: (No distinct is being called however)
*Also do not want solution which forces client side evaluation, since its large query

[EF Core 3.1 throws an exception for Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412799/ef-core-3-1-throws-an-exception-for-contains)

Using Net Core 3.1

```
public partial class Property
{
    public Property()
    {
        AddressChangeRequest = new HashSet<AddressChangeRequest>();
        CalamityEventHistory = new HashSet<CalamityEventHistory>();
        CutHistoryPropertyChildProperty = new HashSet<CutHistoryProperty>();
       ....}

    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public int? LkPropertyTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? LkZoningId { get; set; 
    public string PropertyIdentifier { get; set; }
    ....


 modelBuilder.Entity<Property>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Property", "PM");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.PropertyIdentifier)
                .HasName("Unique_Property_PropertyIdentifier")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.PropertyIdentifier)
                .HasMaxLength(16)
                .IsUnicode(false);
```

[image]

Comment: I see you have already found https://stackoverflow.com/a/58690829/11683 which your question seems to disprove.

Comment: Which Entity Framework version is used? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156883/ef-core-3-x-contains-in-expression-where-x-is-icollection

Comment: The workaround mentioned is `IEnumerable<string> identifiers` instead of `List<string>`. Does that work?

Answer (score 3):

Please Change Identifiers to Enumerable. This resource below is incorrect. Converting it to Enumerable for identifiers works. Casting to List does not work for me.

[EF Core 3 x.Contains() in expression where x is ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156883/ef-core-3-x-contains-in-expression-where-x-is-icollection)

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PropertyDto>> GetByPropertyIdentifier(List<string> identifiers)
    {
        var identifiersEnumerable = identifiers.AsEnumerable();
        var properties = await _dataContext.Property
            .Where(x => identifiersEnumerable.Contains(x.PropertyIdentifier))
            .ToListAsync();

        return properties.Select(_mapper.Map);
    }
```

Comment: that's exactly what i have mentioned in the comment :)

Comment: `List<string>` works for me (with exactly the same components / versions). Probbly what you have shown is not the real query shape.