# C# EF array intersect in LINQ to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a code first app, and one table "Notification" with column "Tags" which stores tags in one string, separated by ';'. In context, I have a conversion to IEnumerable and vice versa. It all works well when inserting and getting data, but in one service I build filter dynamically, by adding predicates, one by one, and adding final predicate list to query.
Now, I have a situation where I want to filter by Tags, for example, I want all Notifications with Tags "Tag1" and "Tag2". I tried with Contains and Intersect, but I constantly get exceptions because LINQ expression cannot be transleted. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Context:

```
    builder.Entity<Notification>().Property(x => x.Tags).HasConversion
                    (x => string.Join(';', x),
                    x => x.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
);
```

Service:

```
var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<UserNotification>();
IEnumerable<string> tagsFilter = new List<string>() { "Tag1","Tag2" };
filter = filter.And(x => x.Notification.Tags != null); // this line works

// both these lines fail (they are here as alternatives, should give the same result)
filter = filter.And(x => x.Notification.Tags.Any(r => tagsFilter.Contains(r)));
filter = filter.And(x => x.Notification.Tags.Intersect(tagsFilter).Any());
```

The error is (in "Where" clause":

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<UserNotification>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Notification>, 
        inner: u => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(u, "NotificationId"), 
        outerKeySelector: n => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(n, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<UserNotification, Notification>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(u => True && __statuses_0
        .Contains(u.Outer.NotificationStatus) && __types_1
        .Contains(u.Inner.Type) && u.Inner.Tags != null && u.Inner.Tags
        .Any(r => __tags2_2.Contains(r)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: You'll have to apply the filter on the Tags on the client-side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core 3 x.Contains() in expression where x is ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156883/ef-core-3-x-contains-in-expression-where-x-is-icollection)

Comment: Are you sure it is a good design to concatenate the Tags into one string in your Notification table? Wouldn't it be better, and probably be easier, to have a separate table with Tags, and to have a many-to-many relation between Notification and Tags? Every Notification has zero or more Tags, every Tag is used by zero or more notifications. This way it is more easy to change Tags: for instance rename the text, or declare them obsolete. This is code first, so now you can still decide to create a properly normalized database structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the comments, @David - can I somehow force the query to do it on client side, without pulling all unfiltered data to memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working code-first, my advice would be to put your tags in a separate table, and have a many-to-many relation between Notifications and Tags. This will save you a lot of work now, and in the future if you have a big filled database and you need to make changes:

```
public class Notification
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Notification has zero or more Tags (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set; }
    ... // you can add other properties later

    // every Tag is used by zero or more Notifications (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notification {get; set;}
}
```

Because I used the entity framework code first conventions, entity framework recognizes the many-to-many relation between Notifications and Tags. No fluent API nor attributes are needed.

**Requirement**: Given the text of several Tags, give me all Notifications that have all these tags:

```
IEnumerable<string> tagTexts = ...
var notifications = dbContext.Tags.Where(tag => tagTexts.Contains(tag.Text)
    .SelectMany(tag => tag.Notifications)
    .Distinct();
```

**Requirement** Remove all Notifications that have only Tag with text "SQL"

```
string tagText = "SQL";
var notificationsWithOnlyTagSQL = dbContext.Notifications
    .Where(notification => notification.Tags.All(tag => tag.TagText == tagText)
    .ToList();
dbContext.Notifications.RemoveRange(notificationsWithTagSQL);
```

**Requirement** Make sure that all tags with "sql", "SQL", "Sql", etc use the same text: "SQL" (suppose you have a case insensitive database)

```
const string proposedTagText = "SQL";
var tagsToChange = dbContext.Tags.Where(tag => tag.TagText == proposedTagText).ToList();

foreach (var tag in tagsToChange)
{
    tag.TagText = proposedTagText;
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

See how much simpler it is if you have a separate Tag table! Think of how much work this would have been if you had to check the strings of every Notification!

Oh dear, now that we have changed tag "sql" to "SQL", we have several tags with the same TagText. Make sure there is only one left:

```
var tagsSql = dbContext.Tags
    .Where(tag => tag.TagText == proposedTagText)
    .ToList();
var tagToKeep = tagsSql.FirstOrDefault();
var tagsToRemove = tagsSql.Skip(1).ToList();

var notificationsToChange = dbContext.Tags
    .Where(tag => tagIdsToRemove.Contains(tag))
    .SelectMany(tag => tag.Notifications)
    .Distinct();

foreach (var notification in notificationsToChange)
{
    // remove all tagsToRemove from this notification
    notification.Tags.RemoveRange(tagsToRemove);

    // if this notification does not have tagToKeep, add it:
    if (!notification.Contains(tagToKeep))
    {
        notification.Add(tagToKeep);
    }
}

// now that no one uses TagsToRemove anymore, we can remove the tags:
dbContext.Tags.RemoveRange(tagsToRemove);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The following is not even possible in your concatenated string tag method:

After database migration Tag has an added Boolean property: IsObsolete, initially set to false.

**Requirement** Give me all Notifications that have obsolete Tags:

```
var notificationsWithObsoleteTags= dbContext.Tags
    .Where(tag => tag.IsObsolete)
    .SelectMany(tag => tag.Notifications);
```

**Requirement**: remove all obsolete Tags from your notifications

```
var obsoleteTags = dbContext.Tags.Where(tag => tag.IsObsolete).ToList();
dbContext.RemoveRange(obsoleteTags);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Again: consider how much work it would have been for you to do this if you hadn't a separate table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Contains() or Intersect() on server side because LINQ can't convert from string to IEnumerable in SQL.
Use filter by string field instead:

```
    var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<UserNotification>();
    IEnumerable<string> tagsFilter = new List<string>() { "Tag1","Tag2" };
    filter = filter.And(x => x.Notification.Tags != null); // this line works
    
    foreach (var tag in tagsFilter) {
        // search for tag with heading and trailing ',' to distinct tags 'ham' and 'hamburger'
        filter = filter.And(x => ("," + x.Notification.Tags + ",").Contains("," + tag + ","));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, note that here .Tags property is not string, but string[], so I have two enumerables to intersect.