# EF Core : Filtering by not mapped boilerplate properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some entity classes that contain a not mapped integer property that is used to categorize the data, which is represented by the entity.

```
 public partial class HouseEntity
 {
     [NotMapped]
     public int DataCategory { get => 5; }

     // other mapped properties

     // mapped bit property
     public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to be able to write complex filtering statements, based on in-memory constants and also based on stored values like this one:

```
public IEnumerable<HouseEntity> GetHouses()
{
    List<int> categoryPermissions = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}; // usually obtained through service 
        
    return context.HouseEntities
                  .Where(he => categoryPermissions.Contains(he.DataCategory) ||  he.IsPublic == true )
                  .ToList();
}
```

The problem is that the linq statement above throws an exception because it can not be compiled to sql.

Are there any workarounds or any other approaches for filtering by hardcoded in-memory properties?

Comment: Are you sure that ef core can not compile `he => categoryPermissions.Contains(he.DataCategory)` to SQL? I think it should be compiled to SQL. May be the problem lies anywhere.

Comment: What is your EF Core version? Please upgrade to EF Core 3.1. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will try your suggestions and check the framework version and will reply afterwards.

Comment: You example seems a little bit adapted for the sake of simplicity. In this case it might help to show us the real queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that I was unable to run the code above with Entity Framework Core 3.1.1

The problem is that I can not make EF to "look into the future" and convince it to get the the value from the property, probably because it requires an entity instance and there is no way of knowing  that the getter will return a constant value across all instances.

I also substituted the `List<int>` with `IEnumerable<int>` again achieving no positive results.

A workaround I found for my specific scenario was this one:

```
public IEnumerable<HouseEntity> GetHouses() 
{ 
   List<int> categoryPermissions = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}; // usually obtained through service 

   int category = (new HouseEntity()).DataCategory;

   return context.HouseEntities
                 .Where(he => categoryPermissions.Contains(category) || he.IsPublic == true )
                 .ToList(); 
}
```

Although this seems a little bit like a non sense,
such approach was needed, because I needed to be able to write a method for generating universal where clause `Expression`s, which does not work with a concrete Entity class but with an Interface, enforcing the Entities, which implement it, to categorize themselves through the not mapped property and providing access to some common properties like the IsPublic column.

Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Since it's `[NotMapped]`, you cannot perform the query against the database.

But you could to little in memory tricks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<HouseEntity> GetHouses()
{
    List<int> categoryPermissions = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}; // usually obtained through service 
        
    // note the tolist here
    return context.HouseEntities.ToList()
                  .Where(he => categoryPermissions.Contains(he.DataCategory) ||  he.IsPublic == true )
                  .ToList();
}
```

Alternatively you can use extension methods to obtain a more fluent syntax - it would also to help you improve performance: i.e.: execute the database indexed part first, then "ToList" and then the in-memory part. Although, it can be tricky to write an `OR` like expression by chaining queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know that this works, but the problem is that there are too many records in the database and it is not preferred to query them all and filter them in-memory to return only a small subset of them if the user does not have the permissions needed. I will check the advise from your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

How would you write your own SQL query with WHERE statement using a non-existing column? You can't.

What you can do is filter by those properties that are mapped to columns and then after the query returns the result from the database filter by those properties that are not mapped, because by then you'll operating on a collection stored in memory:

```
public IEnumerable<HouseEntity> GetHouses()
{
    List<int> categoryPermissions = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}; // usually obtained through service 
        
    return context.HouseEntities
                  .Where(he => he.IsPublic == true)
                  .ToList()
                  .Where(he => categoryPermissions.Contains(he.DataCategory))
                  .ToList();
}
```

Also consider returning a `List` of `HouseEntity` or `IReadOnlyList` because this is what you are returning in the end.

---

Also, your query may not be working because of `Contains()` called on a list. Try using `IEnumerable` or updating to EF Core 3.1 More info on the issue:

- [EF Core 3 x.Contains() in expression where x is ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156883/ef-core-3-x-contains-in-expression-where-x-is-icollection)
- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/17599

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will have to perform some tests with changing the int List with IEnummerable. Please note that having two successive where clauses like the way you suggest they result in connecting the two predicates with the logical operator `and` not with the logical operator `or` as needed.

Comment: You're right, I missed that `or`. Knowing that, my answer is no longer valid. Still, I'm going to leave it as it is with this commentary. Thanks for the response.